# What is the difference when I use gridapi in the controller in following way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

1. vm.gridApi = gridApi where vm = this and
2. $scope.gridApi = gridApi in 
   onRegisterApi function?

Will it be correct if I use in the following way?

```
vm = this;
vm.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
            vm.gridApi = gridApi;
            gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit(null, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue != oldValue) {
                    rowEntity.isDirty = colDef.name;

                    // $scope.$apply();  <-- can't use this with vm
                    vm.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
                }
            });
        };
```

I want to use vm, because I want to follow this [angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers).
Note: To use $scope, I have to inject $scope in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Both have their uses. First, some history ...**

$scope is the "classic" technique while "controller as" is much more recent (as of version 1.2.0 officially though it did appear in unstable pre-releases prior to this).

Both work perfectly well and the only wrong answer is to mix them in the same app without an explicit reason. Frankly, mixing them will work, but it will just add to the confusion. So pick one and roll with it. The most important thing is to be consistent.

Which one? That depends on you. There are many more examples out there of $scope, but "controller as" is picking up steam as well. Is one better than the other? That's debatable. So how do you choose?

**Comfort**

I prefer the "controller as" because I like hiding the $scope and exposing the members from the controller to the view via an intermediary object. By setting this.*, I can expose just what I want to expose from the controller to the view. You can do that with $scope too, I just prefer to use standard JavaScript for this. In fact, I code it like this:

```
var vm = this;

vm.title = 'some title';
vm.saveData = function(){ ... } ;

return vm;
```

This feels cleaner to me and makes it easy to see what is being exposed to the view. Notice I name the variable that I return "vm" , which stands for viewmodel. That's just my convention.

With $scope I can do the same things, so I'm not adding or detracting with the technique.

Now Some more points :

1. $scope is being removed in Angular 2.0. Thus, using this would be an approach others want to follow as the date of release of Angular 2.0 comes closer.
2. The Angular documentation explicitly tells you that using this is recommended. That, in addition to the fact that $scope is being removed is enough reason for me to never use $scope.
3. this is more readable

**Short answer:**

```
this
```

When the controller constructor function is called, this is the controller.
When a function defined on a $scope object is called, this is the "scope in effect when the function was called". This may (or may not!) be the $scope that the function is defined on. So, inside the function, this and $scope may not be the same.

```
$scope
```

Every controller has an associated $scope object.
A controller (constructor) function is responsible for setting model properties and functions/behavior on its associated $scope.
Only methods defined on this $scope object (and parent scope objects, if prototypical inheritance is in play) are accessible from the HTML/view. E.g., from ng-click, filters, etc.

**Thanks & Cheeers**